# Как программно отключить кулер на корпусе?

Tags: железо

Здравствуйте!

На корпусе стоит кулер, в 5400 rpm. Как понимаете, шума дофига. Он подключен на прямую к блоку питания и к материтнке. 
Как программно ОТКЛЮЧИТЬ кулер, а когда требуется - включить?

**PS** Программе SpeedFan не работает. Мне нужно именно ВЫКЛЮЧИТЬ кулер, а когда надо - включить, а SpeesFan лишь снижает обороты. Если я не прав, поправее пожалуйста!

Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблемы с железом не являются допустимой темой Stackoverflow на русском языке.

Comment: @decyrus, кто сказал?

Answer (score 1):

Просто перепаяй его на 5 вольт и он будет работать очень тихо. С блока питания идёт по 4 провода: два посередине  - это минусы, а а два крайних один 12, а другой 5 вольт. Вычисли это потом откуси проводок плюсовой у куллера (пополам) нарасти проводок и примотай к 5 вольтовому выводу. Я сделал себе так всё куллеры.

Comment: То есть подключить проводов с 12 вольтам к проводку с 5 вольтами?  Оборотность кулера падает?Чем достигается этот эффект? Не пойму просто. Спасибо.

Comment: на куллеры всегда подаётся 12 вольт и они работаю по максимуму. Подайте вместо 12 5 вольт и будет вам счастье.

Comment: То есть снизить его оборотность?

Comment: Да просто снизить, тогда он будет работать почти бесшумно.

Comment: Это не подходит. Проще купить другой куллер.На коком проводке сделать кнопку(механическую) включения/выключения куллера?

Comment: Как сделать компьютер бесшумным?   http://prostolinux.ru/kak-sdelat-kompyuter-besshumnyim/

Answer (score 1):

Куда бы ни был включен кулер, питающий провод у него один. Отключение кулера, равно как и скорость оборотов проще всего обеспечить с помощью переменного резистора с выключателем. В свое время Zalman продавал кулеры с резисторами в комплекте (для варианта - менее шумный).
Так что, это наиболее оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Кулер как подключен? В материнку или грубо, в 5 вольт от БП? В последнем случае ничего не выйдет! А вот если в материнку, да тремя или четырьмя проводами - то это в BIOS Setup настраивается.

Comment: @Anton  Reshin,я не помню названия проводов, нотмогу описать. Тогкий аровод с 2 пиновой коробкой мвденькой белой идет к материнской плате, при его отключении кулер работает, но в биосе не отображены обороты,  а запитан большим проводом к БП. Я так понял програмно его не отключить.